# How to execute bitcoin transactions in a decentralized way?

Tags: transactions, private-key

I'm working on a project to automate donating bitcoins to charity every time Elon Musk mentions `#Bitcoin` on Twitter. To make this possible, people who want to donate would need to send bitcoins to an address holding all the coins in the meantime. And then when the condition is met (Elon mentions #bitcoin in a tweet), the bitcoins would be sent to the bitcoin address of a charity.

Obviously for security reasons, I shouldn't know the private key of the address holding the donations or that would allow me to steal the donations. So I'm trying to figure out how can the donations be sent to charity without any one person knowing the private key of the wallet?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is called `Oracle` and as we speak there are no perfect implementations of it. It's an ongoing problem to be solved for example it's hard to weed out false information. I advise you to read more about it outside this forum.